# NSDictionary - avoiding nils

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsdictionary

I have a lot of textfields(about 20) in a view controller. After the user fills out the textfields (some maybe empty), I create ab NSDictionary and send it to my datacenter class. The NSDictionary I am creating looks like this:

```
textfield1 -> textfield1_value
textfield2 -> textfield2_value
textfield3 -> textfield3_value
textfield4 -> textfield4_value
```

The thing is, anytime the user leaves a field blank, a nill is put into value. This causes the NSDictionary to be initialized abruptly/prematurely (if thats the right word). Is checking for a nil for each and every 20 textfield my only option here? I feel like there's got to be a better way. Thanks.

**Sorry about the confusion. I am initializing the NSDictionary like this:**

```
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectAndKeys: obj1, key1, obj2, key2, ..., nil];
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"This causes the NSDictionary to be initialized abruptly/prematurely"*?

Comment: I assume he uses initWithObjects: and then gives all the textfield_values as arguments: Any value being nil will "prematurely" end the list of arguments.

Answer (score 5):

If you use **setObject:forKey:** method, you should be careful not to pass a *nil* as value, which will raise an *NSInvalidArgumentException*.

If you use **setValue:forKey:** method, setting *nil* as the value actually removes the key from the dictionary, which saves the memory. This method will be really helpful to remove a key from the dictionary(*actually a memory*) in situations where you don't want it at all. If you use this method you don't have to check for nil in the text fields, which saves you some time too.

Answer (score 2):

In order to store `nil` in a `NSMutableDictionary`, you should wrap it with `[NSNull null]`, cause can't put `nil` in.

The way you will check if a text field is empty actually depends on your code, but checking for `nil` is compulsory, if you plan to store such a value in.

Comment: I didn't know about NSNull. Thanks!